# Extensions of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have just finished learning about field extensions and such. In particular I am interested in the minimum polynomial of $a$ in some field extension $K$ of $F$. Particularly I have learned about the minimum polynomials of an element $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ for some field $\mathbb{F}$.

I am wondering, what is the connection between the two? As far as I know, $L(V,V) \cong  M_n(\mathbb{F})$ and $L(V,V)$ is not a field. So, how are the two definitions of minimum polynomials similar or different? Does the concept of a minimum polynomial hold for other algebraic structures such as rings or groups?

I originally thought something along the lines of $\mathbb{F}(A)$. But then realized that it this would still not form a field.

Comment: Observe that $K$ is a vector space over $F$, and multiplication by an element of $K$ is an $F$-linear map, hence it makes sense to speak of its minimal polynomial in the sense of linear maps on vector spaces. Indeed if one fixes a basis for $K$ as a vector space over $F$, then for every $a\in K$ the linear map $x\mapsto ax$ can be identified with a matrix in $M_n(F)$, and this defines an embedding $K\hookrightarrow M_n(F)$.

Comment: What is an embedding?

Comment: In this context, just an injective ring homomorphism.

Comment: Googling "embedding math" the first result for me is [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding).